# React multipage dApp not working on IPFS

Tags: dapp-development, react, ipfs

I am creating a create app with multiple pages and it uses web3-react (npm package) but when I publish this on IPFS, it doesn't work as expected, and I have tried react-snap for creating static HTML but it's not working either any suggestions?

Without react-snap, it just shows this error:
`react-dom.production.min.js:189 Error: Invariant failed at tiny-invariant.js:8:15`

and with react-snap I am not even able to build the project.

Comment: it would be good if you could specify your question a bit more, what exactly is not working as usual, and at best add some code and error logs / terminal output

Comment: updated, thanks